# What are the cheat codes for Age of Empires 2?

Tags: cheats, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I recall there one being 'beefsteakjimmies' but that's the only one I can remember. What are all of the codes and what do they give you in the game?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you mean CHEESE STEAK JIMMY'S.

Here are a list of all the cheats taken from [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/924259-age-of-empires-ii-gold-edition):

- CHEESE STEAK JIMMY'S:  +1000 Food
- ROBIN HOOD: +1000 Gold
- ROCK ON: +1000 Stone
- LUMBERJACK: +1000 Wood
- NATURAL WONDERS: Control nature (lose control of men)
- RESIGN: Defeat yourself
- BLACK DEATH: Destroy all the enemies
- WIMPYWIMPYWIMPY: Destroy yourself
- FURIOUS THE MONKEY BOY: Get a Furious Monkey Boy
- HOW DO YOU TURN THIS ON: Gives a 'cobra' car
- TO SMITHEREENS: Gives a saboteur
- I LOVE THE MONKEY HEAD: Gives a VDML
- AEGIS: Immediate Building
- TORPEDOx: Kills opponent x
- POLO: Remove Shadow
- MARCO: Reveal Map
- WOOF WOOF: Turns    birds into super dogs
- I R WINNER: Victory

Comment: You enter the cheat codes pressing enter and writing in the console / chat area

Comment: "FURIOUS THE MONKEY BOY" I didn't know about this one.

Comment: "FURIOUS THE MONKEY BOY" only works in AoE2 Conquerors

Comment: I seem to remember something like 'big daddy' or something? This spawned a sportscar with a rocket launcher on its roof.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma - that would have been for the first Age of Empires

Comment: Does 'pepperoni pizza' or something like that give 1000 food too?